# How to map color with the dynamic data

Tags: javascript

I have an array of time, color in hex (which goes from blue to yellow) and a data array. I want to assign color to each data at the time that it was received. The min value will have yellow color and the max blue. So its a range. The values in the data array are dynamic.

For eg at time 07:00 am, the data received is 47 then the color will light yellow (hex).

Could anyone of you provide me an example on how to code this in javascript? Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question and see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that given your minimum and maximum values that you can find the current value percentage.  Something like 100 * (current - min) / (max - min) should give you a number (when rounded) between 0 and 100.  This number can then be used in the same way that the color variable is set in the demo below to give you a color between yellow and blue.

Rather than blend through white, you could also blend through green.  That would be a matter of choice I guess.  If you wanted to do that then I can update the color formula or you can probably figure it out yourself.

I updated the demo with a blend through green.  There is too much green in my opinion but you can adjust the color as you like using a formula that biases yellow and blue rather than a linear blend.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("gradients");
for (var i = 0; i<100; i++){
  var color = (i < 50) ? "hsl(60, 100%, " + (50 + i) + "%)" : "hsl(220, 100%, " + (150 - i) + "%)"
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.style.backgroundColor = color;
  parent.appendChild(el);
}

var parent2 = document.getElementById("gradients2");
for (var i = 0; i<100; i++){
  var color = "hsl(" + (55 + 1.5*i) + ", 100%, 50%)";
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.style.backgroundColor = color;
  parent2.appendChild(el);
}
```

```css
#gradients, #gradients2 { border: solid 1px; margin-bottom: 1em; }
#gradients div { height: 1px; }
#gradients2 div { height: 1px; }
```

```html
<div id="gradients"></div>
<div id="gradients2"></div>
```